# Rspec - how to write a test for class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Being new to RoR and Rspec I am struggling to write a test for this scenario.

```
# Table name: countries
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  code           :string(255)      not null
#  name           :string(255)
#  display_order  :integer
#  create_user_id :integer          not null
#  update_user_id :integer
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime
#  eff_date       :date
#  exp_Date       :date
```

I want to test this method in the country model:

```
 def self.get_default_country_name_order
        countries = Country.in_effect.all.where("id !=?" ,WBConstants::DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID).order("name")
    result = countries
  end
```

In my country_spec I have this:

```
describe Country do
  before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  let(:user){create(:user)}
  let(:country3){create(:country,code:"AUS", name:"Australia", create_user:user, eff_date: Time.new(9999,12,31), exp_date: Time.new(9999,12,31))}

  after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

This country will be expired, a have a named scope on the model which filters out the expired countries.  My test should be something like this:

```
it "should not include an expired country" do
   c = Country.get_default_country_name_order
  end
```

Is this correct so far?  The test does not seem to return anything from the method however?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is proper direction.

To fix problem with persisting your `Country` models, you should either change this:

```
let(:country3){create(:country,code:"AUS", name:"Australia", create_user:user, eff_date: Time.new(9999,12,31), exp_date: Time.new(9999,12,31))}
```

to this:

```
before {create(:country,code:"AUS", name:"Australia", create_user:user, eff_date: Time.new(9999,12,31), exp_date: Time.new(9999,12,31))}
```

or in your test call `:country3`:

```
it "should not include an expired country" do
  country3
  c = Country.get_default_country_name_order
end
```

`let(:country3)` is only "registering" a method to be called (in your example, it populates database), but it is not performed automatically. As long as you don't need the value to be returned from this method, you should stick to `before`, which will execute the code automatically.

On the other hand, you might want to test returned value from your `Country` model. Something like:

```
it "should not include an expired country" do
  example_country = country3
  c = Country.get_default_country_name_order
  expect(c).to eq example_country
end
```

Hope that helps.

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

Example of how to structure the spec with multiple occurrences of `before`

```
describe Country do
  before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  let(:user){create(:user)}
  let(:country3){create(:country,code:"AUS", name:"Australia", create_user:user, eff_date: Time.new(9999,12,31), exp_date: Time.new(9999,12,31))}

  after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  describe "#get_default_country_name_order" do
    # you can register another "before"
    before {create(:country,code:"AUS", name:"Australia", create_user:user, eff_date: Time.new(9999,12,31), exp_date: Time.new(9999,12,31))}

    # or simpler - this will call your method 
    # before "it", and create the record
    # before { country3 }

    it "should not include an expired country" do
      # your expectations here
    end
  end
```

Comment: I've updated my OP to show how the describe and before do. Does this affect your answer at all?

Comment: Hey @user3437721, included code doesn't really change much, you might have more than one occurrence of `before` in your specs. Please check updated answer for an example of how you can structure your spec